# How can I find lesbians?

Tags: fable-3

I am trying to find a few comely lasses for my *Fable III* princess to settle down with, but I am having a devil of a time finding anyone of the Sapphic persuasion for her. In *Fable II* I was usually able to find at least 1 resident of the Island in each settlement, but that does not seem to be the case here (I like to try to keep each marriage local if I can, variety is the spice of life ;p ).

What, if any, actions can I undertake to satisfy the yearnings of my Princess's heart?

Comment: Shouldn't this be on Dating.SE?

Comment: Generally speaking, you shouldn't put tags (such as game names) in the question title. Therefore I vote this question be renamed to simply "Where do I find lesbians?"

Comment: @dlras2 - I definitely second this statement. As a bonus, it will probably get about 1000x more views due to google searches ;)

Comment: I've found plenty, not sure where you're loo-...ooohh you mean in the _game_. Right. Sorry, can't help.

Comment: Is there a prize for best non-skyrim non-mw3 question? Because this should win it.

Comment: @Wipqozn I looked for Dating.SE and there's no such thing. :( (Relationships.SE is still in commitment phase. I wonder if people with relationship problems would risk commitment to a Q&A website)

Comment: Can you marry prostitutes? My research suggests all the prostitutes in Fable III are bisexual.

Comment: @RavenDreamer The player can cultivate relationships will all classes of NPC except for soldiers/guards and children. If the orientations are compatible, marriage is an option.

Comment: Should I ammend the title to the more accurate "How can I find lesbians and bisexual women?"?

Comment: This SE has the best question titles sometimes.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I never had a problem finding gay ladies to date and marry in Fable III (before I scratched up my copy of the game when my xbox fell over, d'oh!). There were times when I had as many as four wives (and several other ladies on the back burner, ready to step in). I even had two in the same town, once. (That didn't go very well once they found out about each other.)

I generally found them just by pretty much wandering up to random ladies in the town or area I was in and talking to them so I could see whether or not I could get them to date me. (Similar to my real-life strategy.) I think the gay/straight ratio in most areas is less than 50/50, but not by much. 35/65 or even 40/60, maybe. This is all just speculation on my part, and speculation based on memories of a game I haven't played in at least eight months. But that's how I remember the game.

Update: I've been playing through again. The ratio is drastically lower than I remembered, but there seems to be at least one or two lesbians in ever town. The number of gay men seems to be the same.

'Nother update: A very easy way to find lesbians crops up if you've finished the game as a good guy with enough money to save most or all of the citizens of Albion. Just about everybody you meet loves you if you finish the game that way, so if you bump into a lady and the popup says she's your Best Friend, that means she's straight. If you bump into a lady and the popup says she's your Love, that means she's gay or bisexual. Vice versa for bumping into men around town. This still requires you to check each individual for their preference, but at least now you can do it without Interacting with them.

Comment: I remember basically what you do: interested people can be found in pretty much every town, and there's no way to do it other than asking one at a time.

Comment: The ratio seems much lower in _Fable III_ than my experience in _Fable II_. I have found a few that I can't even befriend.

Comment: @CyberSkull Are you dressed nicely? Seem to remember that if you were dressed nice, and presented well, that more people would be fonder of you. Not 100% sure, been awhile.

Comment: @Doozer I can't confirm from the game, but that idea sounds familiar to me, too.